# Elements of one sequence in terms of the elements of another sequence

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

I have two related sequences of non-negative integers: $x_1, x_2,\dots ,x_N$ and $y_1, y_2,\dots ,y_N$. I can get one sequence from the other ({$x_i$} from {$y_i$}, and {$y_i$} from {$x_i$}). However, I only managed to get a general expression in one way:

$$ y_i = \sum _{k=i} ^N x_k (k-i+1)$$

I wish to find an equivalent expression to get any $x_i$ in terms of the $y_i$. How can I do that?

Comment: It's a system of linear equations.  You need to invert the coefficient matrix.  Try it for small values of $N$ and see if you can find a pattern.

Comment: Hint: $
\require{cancel}
y_{i}-y_{i+1} = x_i + \sum_{k=i+1}^N x_k \left((\cancel{k-i}+1) - (\cancel{k-i})\right) = \sum_{k=i}^N x_k\,$.

Comment: Thank you @saulspatz , I will try

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, I noticed that and tried to start from $i=N$, which gives $x_N=y_N$, and advance backward (in that way I managed to  get all the $x_i$s), but I still cannot find a (simple) general expression (for any $N$)

Comment: Actually, the pattern is very simple.  I did a (very) few computer experiments, and noticed it at once.

Comment: @user1420303 You can write that as $\,\left(y_i-y_{i+1}\right) = x_i + \left(y_{i+1}-y_{i+2}\right)\,$.

Comment: @saulspatz, dxiv,  Thanks! I arrived to the solution following the saulspatz approach.